# R- distinguishing argument values

Tags: r

Hi I want to pass a list of arguments into my main function to use two sub functions.

```
f<-function(a,...){
   x1<-f1(...)
   x2<-f2(...)
   }
```

Suppose f1 takes an argument with name "a" and f2 takes an argument with name "a". How can I solve this problem. The name "a" is used inside the main function and the two subfunctions. I am trying to distinguish what name "a" is for different functions but it seems to be a very difficult task.

I can give a more specific example

```
f<-function(x,...){
       print(mean(x)) 
       x1<-dnorm(...)
       x2<-dbinom(...)
       }
```

Obviously, dnorm and dbinom use name "x" as inputs. But, I want to use a different value of x for each of the sub functions. Furthermore, I want to use name "x" inside the main function to calculate it's mean because the main x is a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Since they have the same name, you'll need some way of distinguishing them or they will simply clash, as you've pointed out. There's really not much magic beyond that: you've spotted the issue.

You'll also need a way of keeping `dbinom`-specific arguments out of `dnorm`, because `dnorm` throws an error if you give it a `size` argument, for example.

You can write out all the relevant args, for example:

```
f<-function(x,dnx, mean=0, sd=1, dnlog=FALSE, dbx, size, prob, dblog=FALSE, ...){
   print(mean(x)) 
   x1<-dnorm(x=dnx, mean, sd, log=dnlog)
   x2<-dbinom(x=dbx, size, prob, log=dblog)
}
```

or supply them as lists:

```
 f<-function(x,
             dn_args=list(x=0, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE), 
             db_args=list(x=5, size=10, prob=0.5, log = FALSE), ...){
   print(mean(x)) 
   x1<-do.call(dnorm, dn_args)
   x2<-do.call(dbinom, db_args)
  }
```

You can also consider whether you need to refactor the function into smaller pieces.  :)